# How can I copy Hive database from Device to PC

Tags: android, android-sqlite, flutter-hive

[Device File Explore](https://aboutreact.com/see-saved-data-of-the-sqlite-database-in-device/) can be used to [copy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0448269e-9dc5-4320-88a0-641ae0d01d1f/how-i-can-copy-my-sqlite-database-from-device-to-pc?forum=xamarinforms) sqlite database from android to windows/linux.

How can I copy Hive database . I could not locate it using Device File Explorer?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/891